# Given the following three lines along the edge of a unit cube, describe all lines that meet all three of these.

Tags: parametric, parametrization

[image]

My attempt:
Parametric equations for the three lines are given by

(x,y,z) = (t,0,0)

(x,y,z) = (0,s,1)

(x,y,z) = (1,1,r)

Any line meeting all three of these must pass through a point satisfying each of the above equations, but I don't know how to go about calculating this.

More generally, some intuition behind using parameterisations of planes and lines to find their intersection would be appreciated!

Comment: You're on the right path so far! Hint: any two of these points determine a unique line. Pick two, describe the line they determine, and figure out the conditions for the third point to be on that line.

Comment: Please take the time to enter _all_ of the important parts of your question as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do the show up in summaries.

Comment: Your parametrization of the first line is incorrect: is should be $(t,0,0)$.

Comment: Hint: three nonzero vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ are colinear iff their scalar triple product vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

The lines are parallel to (x,y,z) axes, but are pairwise skew. Skew lines by definition do not meet, and the three lines have no intersecting lines for any of the three pairs.

Comment: The three given lines don't meet, but I am asked to find lines that meet all three of these lines, not whether they meet. As an example, I think the line ( 1- (0.5(t), 1 - t, -1 + t ) satisfies this (sub in t = 0,1,2 and it should be a point on each line). My problem is that I don't know where to start find all of these lines.